# How to inject excel data to embed powerpoint chart with VBA

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I want to know how we can inject excel data into embed powerpoint chart.

Any information that I search taught me how to do it, but with create new presentation. I need to **update** the existing chart from powerpoint using data from excel.

And the method should not be update link or something. Because I deal with more than hundred charts, I'm afraid linked method will take huge resource that cannot handle by my device. The other reason is I need to keep the chart editable in powerpoint (something that cannot done with paste link method).

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it depends of the version of you office. I have 2016 office, so it is very simple to do

these are the steps

1. Go to INSERT and lok for "Tables", then the opcion called (excel)
2. An excel view is going to open, then in the sheets you can inser your information, make a table format also
3. In the excel view the go to Insert, Recommended graphics and select the one you want

here some photos

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1OPN.png)

[excel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kxOS.png)

Comment: Hi Cristian, unfortunately I'm still on office 2013 / 2010. Any other method, you can suggested?